# How to track Signer's IP Address in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

We need a IP address of Signer for audit purpose. So how we can track a IP of signer apart form certificate of completion.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer for each of your questions. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [listAuditEvents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listAuditEvents/) api to retrieve the envelope audit history. **ClientIPAddress** is one of the properties present in the envelope audit history.

> GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/audit_events

```
{
 "auditEvents": [
 {
  "eventFields": [
    { "name": "logTime",  "value": "2017-05-12T14:27:20.3541245Z" },
    { "name": "UserName", "value": "Jane Doe" },
    { "name": "UserId", "value": "c780706d-ac28-45a8-9c05-4adc6860e488" },
    { "name": "Action", "value": "Signed" },
    { "name": "Message", "value": "The envelope was Signed by Jane Doe" },
    { "name": "EnvelopeStatus", "value": "created" },
    { "name": "ClientIPAddress", "value": "128.384.222.11" },
    { "name": "Language", "value": "english" }
  ]
  },
 ]
}
```