# How to retrieve IP address from a docusign document given the Doc ID (not EnvelopeId)

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusignapextoolkit

I am trying to extract more information from the set of DocuSign pdfs. These pdfs have Doc ID at the bottom right. I don't have EnvelopeIds or any other information but Doc ID  I wanted to know if I can use Docusign API to extract the e-signer details.

Comment: Can you send an image of what you mean "at the bottom right" ? are you sure it's Doc ID?

Comment: Do you know how to do this given an EnvelopeId?

Comment: @InbarGazit  I am afraid that I cannot share the image here but it definitely says "Doc ID:" xxxxxxxxx (ID with alphanumerics of length 40)                                                                                                                      This article explains how we can do it using EnvelopeId - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323725/how-to-track-signers-ip-address-in-docusign

Comment: You need to find the envelopeID. I am not sure what you call Doc ID is not an envelopeID that is mischaracterized .

Comment: Is this a one off? you need this one time? or you need to build this into your app?

Comment: @InbarGazit This is a one off and I just need it one time. I can share the image of what I mean by bottom right but I am unable to upload the screenshot here. I have sent you a LinkedIn request.

Comment: Please open the envelope and go to history, you'll see the envelopeID show there

Comment: You should also see the IP Address in the history, no need to make API calls if it's one time thing

Comment: @InbarGazit I will add a little more context and try to explain my need - these are set of curated pdfs that were downloaded from DocuSign and sent over to us as pdf version but each of these pages still have  Doc ID associated to it - I don't have Docusign envelope history. I thought these Doc IDs might be unique (and mean something) and we can trace back to original e-signer even without DocuSign history with API calls from a legitimate Docusign account. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you either the sender or the recipient of the envelope?

Comment: @InbarGazit Neither.

Comment: Then you cannot do this. You are not allowed to get this information, it's not a technical limitation. Only if you are a party in the transaction DocuSign will provide this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only parties to the transaction (envelope) are allowed to retrieve any information about the envelope.

Specifically, if you want to know the IP Address, either via the API or not via the API, you must be either the initiator (sender) of the envelope or one of the recipients.
If you are an administrator of the account, you may be able to transfer ownership of this envelope, or it may be shared with you.